# ViewPager как заблокировать

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Каким образом можно по нажатию определенной клавиши в тулбаре "заставить" временно программу заблокировать "перелистывание" между табами (как свайпом, так и нажатием на заголовки табов)? По нажатию на другую кнопку табы должны разблокироваться.

У меня есть ViewPager и TabLayout. Табы отвечают за фрагменты (пока два):

```
    adapter.addFragment(new mainFragment(),"Общее", bundle);
    adapter.addFragment(new charactersFragment(), "Персонажи", bundle);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

В файле, отвечающим за логику фрагмента:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarMainFrag);
    activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    iconToolbarSave = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_save_icon);
    iconToolbarBack = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_back_arrow);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(iconToolbarBack);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (flag_edit == false) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
              flag_edit = false;
activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(iconToolbarBack);
                mainInfo.setKeyListener(null);
              //????????????
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Ивану за наводку.
В итоге получилось вот что.

CustomViewPager:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

xml активности:

```
 <com.apps.gragas.storydirector.Tools.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Код в активности:

```
viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
...
public void controlTabs(boolean enabled){
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(enabled);
        TabLayoutUtils.enableTabs(tabLayout, enabled);
    }
```

Первая строчка в controlTabs блокирует "листание" между фрагментами, а вторая строчка - не дает переключаться между ними нажатием на заголовки табов.

Код TabLayoutUtils:

```
public class TabLayoutUtils {

    public static void enableTabs(TabLayout tabLayout, Boolean enable){
        ViewGroup viewGroup = getTabViewGroup(tabLayout);
        if (viewGroup != null)
            for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < viewGroup.getChildCount(); childIndex++)
            {
                View tabView = viewGroup.getChildAt(childIndex);
                if ( tabView != null)
                    tabView.setEnabled(enable);
            }
    }

    public static View getTabView(TabLayout tabLayout, int position){
        View tabView = null;
        ViewGroup viewGroup = getTabViewGroup(tabLayout);
        if (viewGroup != null && viewGroup.getChildCount() > position)
            tabView = viewGroup.getChildAt(position);

        return tabView;
    }

    private static ViewGroup getTabViewGroup(TabLayout tabLayout){
        ViewGroup viewGroup = null;

        if (tabLayout != null && tabLayout.getChildCount() > 0 ) {
            View view = tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
            if (view != null && view instanceof ViewGroup)
                viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        }
        return viewGroup;
    }

}
```

В коде фрагмента добавил такую строчку:

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (flag_edit == false) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
              flag_edit = false;
activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(iconToolbarBack);
                mainInfo.setKeyListener(null);
              ((projectsActivity) getActivity()).controlTabs(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Тебе нужно создать свой ViewPager как здесь

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    } 
}
```

Чтобы залочить табы попробуй

`tabLayout.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: Спасибо! То есть мне нужно будет потом определить данный  CustomViewPager в xml активности, из которой работают фрагменты, верно? Если да, то подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно сделать findbyid объекта, который находится вне xml данного фрагмента?

Comment: CustomViewPager нужно указать  в xml активности

- Не получится найти объект который не находится в хml. 

Если ты хочешь управлять из фрагмента TabLayout( например) то тебе нужно передать interface в фрагмент, в котором ты вызовешь метод этого интерфейса

или можешь использовать так ((MainActivity)getActivity).somemethod();

somemethod(); - это твой метод который объявлен в активити